# Angular4 *ngFor how to loop nested array using its key name

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have the following data sample:
[image: sample data]

for now i have two nested loop, but what i want to do is, Is it possible to loop through specific key, such as `*ngFor="let key of myArray.functionalArea"`

My current code is:

```
<span *ngFor="let jobByField of countOfJobsByFields">
  <span  *ngFor="let jobByWorkType of countOfJobsByFields?.workType">
    <li (click)="searchByWorkType(jobByWorkType?._id)"><a>{{ jobByWorkType?._id }}<span class="badge badge-default pull-right item-plus-icon-custom-style">{{ jobByWorkType.total }}</span></a></li>
 </span>
```

and for second key i have this:

```
<span *ngFor="let jobByField of countOfJobsByFields">
  <span  *ngFor="let jobByFunctionalArea of countOfJobsByFields?.functionalArea">
    <li (click)="searchByFunctionalArea(jobByFunctionalArea?._id)"><a>{{ jobByWorkType?._id }}<span class="badge badge-default pull-right item-plus-icon-custom-style">{{ jobByFunctionalArea.total }}</span></a></li>
 </span>
```

Note i can not use the same `<span *ngFor="let jobByField of countOfJobsByFields">` for both because they are separate element in my html.

Comment: you want to iterate each functionalArea, from array?

Comment: let me know if this is helpful for you, https://plnkr.co/edit/KTJbPUzrfUftKhcAU29b?p=preview

Comment: @rish updated my question.

Comment: @rish plunker is the same thing i have done already.

Comment: @rish now check this, https://plnkr.co/edit/cxze8ymG0VyZKEmMrqQK?p=preview

Comment: in first object you have workType, but not in second object?

Comment: see this, https://plnkr.co/edit/r4D4Snvnq4fEcgt7Awd0

Answer (score 1):

Use following code

```
 <span *ngFor="let jobByField of countOfJobsByFields">
<div *ngIf='jobByField.workType'>
    <span  *ngFor="let jobByWorkType of jobByField.workType">
        {{jobByWorkType._id}}
    </span>
</div>

<div  *ngIf='jobByField.functionalArea'>
    <span  *ngFor="let jobByWorkType of jobByField.functionalArea">
        {{jobByWorkType._id}}
    </span>
</div>
```

where JSON:-

```
countOfJobsByFields = [
      {
        workType: [{'_id':'Part Time', 'total':10}, {'_id': 'Full Time', 'total': 20}]
      },
      {
        functionalArea: [{'_id':'IT', 'total':10}, {'_id': 'Management', 'total': 20}]
      }

    ]
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/r4D4Snvnq4fEcgt7Awd0?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but the same thing i have already done, with two loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can :

```
<span *ngFor="let jobByField of countOfJobsByFields">
    <ng-template *ngIf='jobByField.workType'>
        <span  *ngFor="let jobByWorkType of jobByField.workType">
            {{jobByWorkType._id}}
        </span>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template *ngIf='jobByField.functionalArea'>
        <span  *ngFor="let jobByWorkType of jobByField.functionalArea">
            {{jobByWorkType._id}}
        </span>
    </ng-template>
</span>
```

Comment: `countOfJobsByFields` is a long list array, i do not want to use from `0, 1, etc...`, because if order of array items change, it needs to change my code.

Comment: @jones, please check updated answer, I think that can help you

Answer (score 0):

Use following code with ng-container ,it will avoid the extra div that has been used with *ngIf

```
<span *ngFor="let jobByField of countOfJobsByFields">
    <ng-container *ngIf='jobByField.workType'>
        <span  *ngFor="let jobByWorkType of jobByField.workType">
            {{jobByWorkType._id}}
        </span>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container *ngIf='jobByField.functionalArea'>
        <span  *ngFor="let jobByWorkType of jobByField.functionalArea">
            {{jobByWorkType._id}}
        </span>
    </ng-container>
</span>`
```